# Do derived sets have anything similar to derivatives?

Tags: general-topology, descriptive-set-theory

The notation ($A'$, $A^{(n)}$) and the name suggest some similarity, maybe only in a few examples. But I cannot see any.

Comment: What are derived sets?

Comment: It's always hard to prove that there is no serious connection between two topics, but I certainly don't know of any in this case.

Comment: @Christoph This is the standard terminology for the set gotten from $A$ by removing all the isolated points (and is the first hit after googling "derived set"). We can iterate the process (the "Cantor-Bendixson derivative"), taking intersections at limit stages, to define $A^(\alpha)$ for arbitrary ordinals $\alpha$.

Comment: Mathematicians are not very creative with terminology. For example: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal#Mathematics